# PHP 5 installed also Mysqli is installed but not compiling in mac lion

Tags: php, macos, apache, mysqli, native

Ive installed native php and apache on my mac 10.7 and then installed mysql with phpmyadmin
having my localhost root set on sites. Everything is working except when im trying to send mysqli querys. I've checked terminal and mysqli is installed, when running php -m | grep mysql I get 
page works fine with mysql querys but need to replace the due to cooperation with school project group

mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
pdo_mysql

also when checking my phpinfo.php everything seems to be connected, mysqli has equal settings enabled as mysql, I've also copied php.ini and checked the extension I do not have specifik rows where extensions are commented or uncommented these lines do not exist in this php.ini except for the line 
;extension=php_mysqli.dll 
 which is for windows users. 
So I Have everything installed! But still when i run querys with mysqli it does not work, and I dont even get errors, and when I type a test .php with
 `if (function_exists('mysqli')) {
    echo "MySQLI functions are available.
\n";
} else {
    echo "MySQLI functions are not available.
\n";
}` 
Yeah U guessed it it says MySQLI functions are not available

PLEASE HELP I've been going at this the hole day with no success, having a hard time understanding what is happening, so enlightenme! Bestregards

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function in PHP. You need to check for extension, not function.

```
extension_loaded('mysqli');
```

though I see no point in such a verification at all. If mysqli is enabled - just run your queries with it.

Comment: please be specific Im a noob,, what do you meen it does not exist?